# Why docker-compose down deletes my volume? how to avoid this action done by 'down'. (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run docker-compose down without `-v` or `--volumes`, why my data is lost? Does Docker deletes my volume?
When I inspect with `docker volume inspect pgdata`, it shows up always the current timestamp, looks like it is always recreated each time.

But when I just stopped the postgres container with `docker stop <container_id>` and re-run the container, the data is still there. Here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    container_name: bsf-quiz-app
    image: sapkotasuren/bsf-quiz
    ports:
      - "443:8443"
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
  postgresqldb:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=bsfQuiz
      
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

## Updated 20/01/2021

I tried to do it on bind mount way, I see a lot of data being created but still the same issue could not find the record which I have created before on the database, after docker-compose down and up.

I also tried to create named volume using docker command:
`docker create volume postgres`, and mention it on my yaml file and set `external` to `true`. still the same issue!

my yaml file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    container_name: bsf-quiz-app
    image: sapkotasuren/bsf-quiz
    ports:
      - "443:8443"
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
  postgresqldb:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=bsfQuiz

volumes:
  postgres:
    external: true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65096420/596285

Answer (score 11):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_down/), `docker compose down` will **not** delete any volume unless the `-v` option is used.

Answer (score 6):

I have encountered the same behaviour with `docker compose down` - my postgres container is removed including all the data. For me the solution was to use this instead:

```
docker-compose stop
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I switched from MariaDB to Postgres and the down command would clear all volumes in this case. The above command helped.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar experience with both postgres and mongodb mounts - despite the fact that I'm using a named volume in my compose file, after running the `compose down` my databases disappear. Here's what I found.

[Docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_down/) for the `compose down` command states:

> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by `up`.
> ...
> Anonymous volumes are not removed by default. However, as they don’t have a stable name, they are not automatically mounted by a subsequent `up`.

(Your volume is named, not anonymous, but this will become significant later.)

At the same time, the [docker compose volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/07-volumes/) documentation says:

> Running `docker compose up` creates the volume if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise, the existing volume is used and is recreated if it's manually deleted outside of Compose.

Based on the above, named volumes declared in the compose file are re-used and should survive the `docker compose down`.

Now, here's my compose file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        container_name: my-service
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - my-volume:/data
    environment:
      ...
volumes:
  my-volume:
```

I inspected my container and found 3 mounts for my mongo database (postgres probably does something similar) - one mount corresponding to my named volume and two more anonymous mounts:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Name": "8a8e9d0aa777699d6fa72354515f7bc7573b4d6801555c820536d213dfe1401b",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/8a8e9d0aa777699d6fa72354515f7bc7573b4d6801555c820536d213dfe1401b/_data",
        "Destination": "/data/db"
    },
    {
        "Name": "my-service_named-volume",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-service_named-volume/_data",
        "Destination": "/data"
    },
    {
        "Name": "dcbc5de172d12a9c43671b9b67dfef5b9be760b4ee724a636216a36aebf3d81c",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/dcbc5de172d12a9c43671b9b67dfef5b9be760b4ee724a636216a36aebf3d81c/_data",
        "Destination": "/data/configdb"
    }
],
```

I checked timestamps on these volumes and found that my named volume has correct, old timestamp from when I originally created it, but both anonymous volumes are stamped with the date when I ran my `compose down`/`compose up`.

This should explain why we lose our data - upon `compose down` anonymous volumes (which actually contain the data in this case) are not re-mounted - new anonymous volumes are created and mounted with each `compose up`.

When I run `docker volume ls` I can see two other, old orphaned anonymous volumes, which used to contain my data.

My take on this is: We can either use `docker compose start/stop` instead of `up/down` to avoid losing data as Mongo (or Postgres) images decide how they use those sub-directories OR we can mount our volumes to those exact directories they are using, something like:

```
services:
    mongo:
    ...
       volumes:
           - db-vol:/data/db
           - cfg-vol:/data/configdb
volumes:
    db-vol:
    cfg-vol:
```

This is not a Docker issue, just something to be aware of.

Comment: You saved my life! I have been searching this for hours !